# Why does R print the wrong answer for some values?

Tags: r

I just started learning r and was experimenting a bit when I came across this issue.

my code was:

```
options(digits=20)

i <- 0:20

10^i +1
```

and my output was the following :

```
##  [1]                     2                    11                   101
##  [4]                  1001                 10001                100001
##  [7]               1000001              10000001             100000001
## [10]            1000000001           10000000001          100000000001
## [13]         1000000000001        10000000000001       100000000000001
## [16]      1000000000000001     10000000000000000    100000000000000000
## [19]   1000000000000000000  10000000000000000000 100000000000000000000
```

why are the last 5 values missing a one at the end? sorry if this is all messy. im new here too.

thanks for the help.

Comment: `identical(10^15, (10^15 + 1)); identical(10^16, (10^16 + 1))`

Comment: I don't understand why the 10^16 and 10^16 +1 are identical though

Comment: does `?.Machine` help?

Comment: no. it said to use ???.machine but that didn't help at all

Comment: R is case sensitive.

Comment: how does that apply here?

Comment: It applies here that `.machine` ins't `.Machine`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the 'hints' others provided to you via the comments were helpful or not, but basically what you are seeing is the limits of storing very large numbers in a computer.  At some point, you reach a point where the computer can represent the number any longer.  This also applies to very small numbers.  This is sometimes called 'overflowing' or 'underflowing'.  The point of the example

```
identical(10^15, (10^15 + 1))
identical(10^16, (10^16 + 1))
```

is to point out that 10^15 can be handled correctly, but 10^16 cannot, you've reached the breaking point.  The help page at `?.Machine` discusses some of the technical details.  There is a little more info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) but all these discussions get technical quickly.

Comment: This isn't over/under-flowing because you can store numbers approximately 2^(+/-308) in double floating point representation (see `.Machine$double.xmax` and `.Machine$double.xmin`). This is a precision issue, which is related to the accuracy of the base-10 number represented in a base-2 numeral system (see `.Machine$double.eps` and `.Machine$double.neg.eps`).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks for the clarification.